# Current versions of GoogleMobileAds.framework and GoogleCast.framework coexistence in one iOS app

Tags: ios, admob, chromecast, google-cast, bitcode

The current version of GoogleMobileAds.framework is v7.4.1 which was created with bitcode enabled. The current version of GoogleCast.framework is v2.7.1 which was created without bitcode enabled.

In Xcode 7, if I set Enable Bitcode to NO, then the ads framework will generate error. But if I set Enable Bitcode to YES, then the cast framework will generate the error.

So, how to go about use these two frameworks in a project?

Comment: Have you tried this using the latest GoogleCast framework?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the Cast SDK to version 2.10.1 solved this issue for me.  According to [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=637), Bitcode slices are now included in the cast SDK as of 2.10.1.